# FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom for VS2008 and VS2010 side-by-side

Tags: f#, compilation, compatibility, codedom, side-by-side

I'm using FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom (from the [PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/)) to dynamically create F# classes. The problem is, that I have both VS2008 and VS2010 on my computer side-by-side (they works fine), and using F# in this configuration is buggy at best:

- If I don't install InstallFSharp.msi, then under VS2008 the built classes complain about not finding FSharp.Core (even if they're referenced)
- If I install InstallFSharp.msi, then under VS2008 the built classes will use the F# built for VS2010, and will throw a binary-incompatibility exception, because it will load the .net4 variant:

  FSC: error FS0219: The referenced or default base CLI library 'mscorlib' is binary-
  incompatible with the referenced F# core library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
  F#\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll'. Consider recompiling the library or making an explicit reference 
  to a version of this library that matches the CLI version you are using.
- If I replace the F# found at the previous location to the separately installed dll-s, then of course VS2010 will complain about binary-incompatibility

Am I overlooking something, or they won't simply work for a shared environment like this? This might mean real problems when I deploy the applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem myself - the trunk of our source tree is set up to build with VS 2008, while our latest branch upgrades to VS 2010.  The F# situation is wearisome, to say the least.

The answer that we've found is to use the --noframework compiler flag.  With that option set, you can (must) specify which mscorlib.dll and System.dll you want to use, and therefore can build against any supported .NET framework.

Comment: It seems in F# 2.0 the ImageRuntimeVersion of the generated assembly is v4.0.xxx by default. That changes to v2.0.xxxx when adding a reference to the v2.0 version of mscorlib.dll. This works even if I don't set --noframework, I just have to add the explicit reference.

Comment: Interesting!  I get a compiler error if I attempt to -r mscorlib.dll without the --noframework flag.  What version of the compiler are you using that allows this?

Comment: Sorry, I think I got it wrong. I'm using the CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider with CompileAssemblyFromSource(...). It seems they automatically add the --noframework flag (even if I don't reference mscorlib.dll explicitly), so it _is_ actually set when the compiler is invoked, even though I don't set it explicitly in the CompilerOptions. I can see the exact command line in the temp file xxx.cmdargs that the CodeProvider creates.

Comment: Yip - I think that's the best explanation we'll get. Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you originally asked the question a while ago, I wonder if you have the most recent PowerPack?  Notably, you ask the question on May 27, but I see on the downloads page that it was last updated on May 30.  I dunno if that affects anything, just pointing it out.

I also edited the question a tiny bit, in case this moves the question to the top and causes Tomas to see it and reply :)

Comment: Mmmm... I ran into this issue with the latest PowerPack, so I doubt the behaviour has changed. The CodeDom compiler is just badly undocumented, and the compiler switches and defaults changed from previous versions - there used to be a --cli-version switch.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a problem that may or may not have been the same with the reghack (Windows 7):
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime]

I believe that the resolution path to find files/compilers means that this hack will cause both to work side-by-side, but have only tested the 2.0 case.
As with any reg hack, you should back up that that reg key first.