# base CLI library 'mscorlib' is binary-incompatible with the referenced F# core library

Tags: .net, f#, compiler-errors

I've built a website that takes code snippets and compiles them and runs them. However, F# is broken on the server. Whenever I try to compile F# code I get the following error message:

> The referenced or default base CLI library 'mscorlib' is binary-incompatible with the referenced F# core library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll'. Consider recompiling the library or making an explicit reference to a version of this library that matches the CLI version you are using.
>
> Error opening binary file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll': Exception of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger+ReportedError' was thrown.

To be clear, this is an error being returned by the compiler, not an error that occurs when the code is run.

The site runs just fine on my development machine and works just fine on a VM I spun up to help diagnose the issue.

The only Google hit for the error message caused me to try cleaning up the F#/.NET install to no avail. I did a repair install of the framework and uninstalled/reinstalled the F# packages I'm using.

Example: http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/ZvXBgizf70q83Fk6VmboHw

F# compilation code: http://bitbucket.org/gobiner/.net-pad/src/tip/DotNetPad/Compilers/FSharpCompiler.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the command-line you are passing to fsc.exe on the server?  It smells like you are `-r`-ing FSharp.Core 4.0 but mscorlib 2.0.  Be sure to pass explicit references to both on the command-line.  Check the Output Window in Visual Studio when you build for a sample command-line.

EDIT

See this question:

[FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom for VS2008 and VS2010 side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925086/fsharp-compiler-codedom-for-vs2008-and-vs2010-side-by-side)

Comment: I'm just calling FSharpCodeProvider so I don't know exactly what command line options get passed. I'd expect FSharpCodeProvider to pass the same options on the server that it does in the other environments.

Comment: In that case, see the question I just linked, seems relevant.  Unfortunately I don't know much about the codedom provider.

Comment: Yes, very relevant.  I think it is a mismatch between a reference to the 32-bit version of FSharp.Core.dll and a reference to a 64-bit version of mscorlib.dll.  The reference path is wrong btw, it should point to c:\program files\reference assemblies\etc.

Comment: Using ProcessExplorer I was able to get the info. It's the same on the working instances as it is on the non-working server. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe" --noframework --nologo -o:"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Gobiner.DotNetPad.Web\App_Data\Gobiner.CSharpPad.Eval.Evil1421939367.exe"  "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\1ailxen1.fs"

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.  You really want a command-line that will explicitly `-r` both FSharp.Core and mscorlib, so you get the right versions of each.  So see if you can get it to add those explicit references.

Comment: fsc.exe apparently has different ideas about referencing assemblies than csc.exe. Changing the assembly references for F# fixed the problem. https://bitbucket.org/gobiner/.net-pad/changeset/d81a6d065e4e

Answer (score 0):

Check what version of .NET you're running against on your dev machine, vs the one in production. The easiest way of doing this is probably to print out `System.Environment.Version`.

I suspect you'll find that your dev machine is using .NET 3.5, and your production machine is using .NET 2.0, or something like that. Check which application pool your application is running in, and you can set the version for that application pool.

Comment: I'm seeing 4.0.30319.1 everywhere: the server and my desktop and the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is your dev machine 32 or 64 bit? Looks like the server is 64, and so it may be a an issue if they are different.

Comment: My home machine and the virtual machine and the server are all 64-bit.